# Sleep function in javascript/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sleep

I am trying to create a "sleep" function where I like to wait 10 seconds before continue with next command.

This doesn't work. No sleep is occuring. How can I put it nicely in a function like I do below "sleep(10000)" which is possible to call?

```js
console.log("Hello");
sleep(10000);
console.log("World!");

function sleep(ms) {

    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: `Promise` is asynchronous. Where as you want something synchronous

Comment: you may use async/await for simulating sth like this but I would not recommend it. Natively a sleep function that blocks execution it is NOT supported

Comment: You have to `await sleep(3000);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `then`, so as to execute code once the promise has been `resolved`.

```js
console.log("Hello");
sleep(10000).then(() => {
    console.log("World!");
})


function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: Then I understand, thank you!